# Bind 9.3 cache-only mode with authoritative name server

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bind

I have bind 9.3 up and running which is designed as a cache-only to get queries from other resources and then cache them to serve clients internally, now I setup my own zone because this is also a web server, I included 2 NS servers pointing to the same IP Address in my zone file, (my server's IP address) and finally glued my record which is now updated I am using Centos 5.8 Final and getting ERROR: One or more of your nameservers did not respond when I query my website using intodns, which I believe simply means that outsides can't communicate with my DNS server because of my named.conf or my firewall, I don't have ip tables installed !

P.S: I am working with chrooted installation and all files are linked probably with the right permissions, I can perfectly resolve anything internally, my custom zone is included in named.rfc1912.zones and I care about security, any ideas ?

```
    include "/etc/rndc.key";
options {
    listen-on port 53 { any; };
        listen-on-v6 port 53 { any; };
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        version         "censored for my pleasure and you misery";
        allow-transfer  { none; };
        allow-recursion { localhost; };
        // Those options should be used carefully because they disable port
        // randomization
           query-source    port 53;
           query-source-v6 port 53;
        allow-query     { any; };
        allow-query-cache { localhost; };
        forward first;
             forwarders {
               208.67.222.222;
               208.67.220.220;
        };
};
controls {
    inet 127.0.0.1 allow { localhost; } keys { "rndc-key"; };
};
logging {
    channel default_debug {
        file "data/named.run";
        severity dynamic;
   };
};
view "localhost_resolver" {
        match-clients      { localhost; };
        match-destinations { localhost; };
        recursion yes;
        zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "/var/named/named.ca";
   };
        include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
};
```

Comment: can you post the content of the `/etc/named.rfc1912.zones` file and also if it's not a secret the domain name so we can try to query it ...

Comment: I got it working by changing match-clients and match-destinations to any, thanks a lot :)